# How would I make an underline exactly the length of any text inputted as well as capitalizing every letter

Tags: c++

Sorry I'm really new to programming and need some assistance. How would I make this happen. This is the function I currently have.

```
void DisplayTitle(string aTitle) {
    cout << "\t" << aTitle << endl;
    cout << "\t--------------\n\n";
}
```

How would I go about making sure that no matter which title is inputted, every character will be capitalized and the underscores will be the same amount of characters as the displayed title above.

Comment: For the underlining:  `const size_t numLetters = aTitle.length(); for (size_t i=0; i<numLetters; i++) cout << "-";`

Comment: Or simply `cout << std::string(aTitle.length(), '-') << "\n\n";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::setfill` combined with `std::setw` from `<iomanip>` as follows:

```
std::cout << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(title.size()) << "";
```

Here, you're telling the stream to use a padding character of `'-'`, then a padded output size that's the length of your title, and then output an empty string.  Because the string is empty, it will pad that entire area.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

void DisplayTitle(const std::string& title, const char* prefix = "\t")
{
    std::cout << prefix << title << "\n";
    std::cout << prefix << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(title.size()) << "" << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    for (std::string title; std::getline(std::cin, title); )
    {
        DisplayTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Example input:

```
One flew over the cuckoo's nest
The birds and the bees
```

Example output:

```
        One flew over the cuckoo's nest
        -------------------------------

        The birds and the bees
        ----------------------
```

Here is a [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vhEfnh9cK) of the above.

---

Oh, it seems I missed the fact your question was asking two things.  You also want to capitalize the title.  You can do that with `std::transform`, and in fact it can even be done without modifying the string:

```
void DisplayTitle(const std::string& title, const char* prefix = "\t")
{
    // Write title in all-caps
    std::cout << prefix;
    std::transform(title.begin(), title.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),
        [](char c) { return std::toupper(c); });
    std::cout << "\n";
    
    // Underline title
    std::cout << prefix << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(title.size()) << "" << "\n\n";
}
```

Here is the updated [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W74jMdWKd) with the above change.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::transform` and `to_upper` to capitalize the string.

You can use `std::string`'s two-parameter constructor which takes a length and a character to generate a sequence of `-` of the same length as the title

Together we get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void DisplayTitle(std::string aTitle) {
    std::transform(aTitle.begin(), aTitle.end(), aTitle.begin(), toupper);

    std::cout << "\t" << aTitle << "\n";
    std::cout << "\t" << std::string(aTitle.length(), '-') << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    for (std::string title; std::getline(std::cin, title); )
    {
        DisplayTitle(title);
    }
}
```

[demo on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PvrqMdW6q)

Comment: This is a “to upper” algorithm, not a “to title” algorithm that the OP wants.

Comment: @Dúthomhas The question says: "every character will be capitalized".

Comment: Heh, you’re right. Sorry.